# R replace values in one column upon matching conditions in another column

Tags: r

I am having trouble finding a solution to this: I want to replace those NA values with some text depending on the name of the variable. Ideally it would do something like:

if variable name is var2 or var3 or var4 replace  in the same row with "text"

```
               variable question
1               var1     <NA>
2               var2     <NA>
3               var3     <NA>
4               var4     <NA>
```

The closest I thought would work was:

```
df$question[df$variable = var2 OR var3 OR var4] <- text
```

it shouldn't be hard, i am just to blind to find the right answers :(.

Comment: It seems like just a syntax issue, you had the right idea. If you use the following conditional statement, it'll work: `(df$variable == "var2"| df$variable == "var3" | df$variable == "var4")`. Note the use of `|` (elementwise comparison)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `text` is the same for `var2, var3, var4` then, this should do the trick. Otherwise, if `text` is different for each `var*`, then update your question and provide us with more details.

```
> df$question <- as.character(df$question)
> df$question[df$variable %in% c("var2", "var3", "var4")] <- "text"
> df
  variable question
1     var1     <NA>
2     var2     text
3     var3     text
4     var4     text
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you! It really was simple as that, similar text for all matching variables.