# Mathematical Operation of a Variable if another Variable is Equal to a String?

Tags: r

I would like help with a simple operation in a data frame. The data frame contains several variables corresponding to countries that are represented with a three letter coding. I would like to add or subtract values from these variables of specific countries.

There is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175795/r-replace-values-in-one-column-upon-matching-conditions-in-another-column). In that case, however, the values are strings.

As an example, say I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(10)

a <- data.frame(country = rep(c("aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc") , times = 3) ,
                year = rep(c(1990 , 1991 , 1992), each = 3) ,
                c = sample(9))
```

giving:

```
  country year c
1     aaa 1990 9
2     bbb 1990 2
3     ccc 1990 4
4     aaa 1991 6
5     bbb 1991 3
6     ccc 1991 7
7     aaa 1992 5
8     bbb 1992 1
9     ccc 1992 8
```

For example, I would like to add 5 to every country corresponding to "aaa", giving:

```
   country year  c
1     aaa 1990 14
2     bbb 1990  2
3     ccc 1990  4
4     aaa 1991 11
5     bbb 1991  3
6     ccc 1991  7
7     aaa 1992 10
8     bbb 1992  1
9     ccc 1992  8
```

Is there an efficient to code to do this? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a two step base R way.

```
i <- df$country == "aaa"
df$c[i] <- df$c[i] + 5
```

A one-liner would be

```
df$c[df$country == "aaa"] <- df$c[df$country == "aaa"] + 5
```

---

## Edit

If column `country` has missing values, `NA`'s, then it's safer to index with

```
i <- which(df$country == "aaa")
```

or with the equivalent one-liner.